# Exporting a hyperlink in Pivot Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel, devexpress-mvc

I currently have a Pivot Grid that exports both a GridView and PivotGrid.  The GridView export correctly creates hyperlinks for users.  However, the PivotGrid export does not.  My question is, is there a way to export the hyperlink so that it is still a hyperlink?

Below is my code for what I have in my Controller to do the export.

```
public ActionResult ExportPivotGrid()
    {
        //A fresh copy of data
        Session["IPDReportsData"] = IPDReport.GetReportData(Session["AdHocDataSource"].ToString(),
            SCCView.Classes.Helper.OfficeId);

        var pivotGridSettings = new PivotGridSettings();
        pivotGridSettings.Name = "ExportPivotGrid";
        pivotGridSettings.BeforePerformDataSelect = (s, e) =>
        {
            MVCxPivotGrid PivotGrid = s as MVCxPivotGrid;
            //Get the current layout of the Pivot Grid
            string layout = (string)(Session["IPDCurrentPivGridLayout"]);
            PivotGrid.LoadLayoutFromString(layout, DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridWebOptionsLayout.DefaultLayout);
        };

        XlsxExportOptionsEx xopt = new XlsxExportOptionsEx();
        xopt.AllowHyperLinks = DefaultBoolean.True;
        xopt.ExportHyperlinks = true;
        xopt.TextExportMode = TextExportMode.Text;
        xopt.ExportType = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.WYSIWYG;

        return PivotGridExtension.ExportToXlsx(pivotGridSettings,
                    Session["IPDReportsData"], true, xopt);

    }
```

I do have this working within the Pivot Grid for the page displayed, but only by using the FieldValueDisplayText method in the settings of the Pivot Grid.  However, when I tried to apply this to my export, the export never loaded.

Any help would be appreciated.